# Cross-compile SQLite3 with multi-threading support

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, arm, embedded-linux

I am using AM1808 ARM9 based board using GCC compiler (UBUNTU 10.04) .
I am using Sqlite3 database management.
I have some requirement regarding handling threads in background having access on database more then 3 or 4 times simultaneously.

I found that I need to Cross compile the Sqlite3 with the Multithreading option(THREADSAFE = 1) enabled.

I am not getting that How i can Cross Compile the Sqlite3.7.15 with the Serialized or Mutithread option enabled ?

I stuck here and due to this i am getting uncertain errors. and my system gets stuck on Thread.

I have already cross compiled my sqlite3.7.15 using following command.

> sudo ./configure
>   --exec-prefix=/media/8CCC8E9BCC8E7F68/SQLIte3/sqliteinstall/  --host=arm --target=arm CC=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
>   AR=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar
>   STRIP=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip
>   RANLIB=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib CFLAGS="-Os"

Comment: Did you start with `./configure --help` ?

Comment: yes. i have checked it and successfully cross compiled using above command.

Comment: I understand that.  But `./configure --help` should tell you what additional options you need in order to build a multi-threaded version.

Comment: ok i need to check it. i will check it and get back to you. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Have you seen http://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html ?

Comment: yes sir i go through the link as you said. i found that when i cross compile with no threadsafe parameters present then by default it will consider the serialized mode. I confused regarding this serialized mode that can i use a single database connection with the multiple threads ?? Actually i want to know which mode is preferable for me ???? multithreading or Serailized ???

Comment: I have checked that by default sqlite3 is cross compiled with serialised mode. and after some googling i found that sqlite is very sensitive to multi thread access with a single database connection so i decided to use thread synchronization method. Now i am trying to use Mutexes.

Comment: I got the solution by using mutexes for locking the database...thank you.